# Java ConcurrentModificationException in foreach Pair, while only reading

Tags: java, for-loop, data-structures

I have this data model called `MyModel`

```
public class MyModel {
    public int userId;

    public MyModel(final int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

and I have this method that checks if this entry is added to the current data `mData` which is `ArrayList<<Pair<Integer, MyModel>>`

```
private boolean isAdded(int id) {
    for (Pair<Integer, MyModel> entry : mData) {
        if (entry.second != null && (entry.first == SOMETHING) {
            if (id == entry.second.userId) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I know I would get `ConcurrentModificationException` if I modify `mData` while looping through it, but this method doesn't really modify the List.

I get the exception on `for (Pair<Integer, MyModel> entry : mData` line.

Why is this happening?

Comment: This code looks good. Can you provide minimal reproducible example values for mData?

Comment: normal `NonNull` datas. Probably I'll take a look if there's some weird multi thread stuff going on. `mData` is definitely modified during AsyncTask so maybe there's corner case I didn't think of...

Comment: Yes. You can take this part out and run to verify this. You didn't provide the full context of where it is being run.

Comment: The cause of the problem is in some other code that you haven't shown us that is modifying the list.

Comment: I'll try locating the source of the issue and let ya'll know. Thank you.